# Anyone with luck on getting KDevelop work under OSX 10.8.3

Tags: ide, terminal, osx-mountain-lion, development-environment, kdevelop

I got KDevelop to install through macports with no issues, but it is very unstable and crashes straightaway. I tried getting it through fink, but fink is not able to find the package anymore?

So I am pretty much stuck with no solution. Maybe an alternative IDE suggestions?

Do not want textMate, have Sublime2 running, not very happy about Eclipse and Xcode. I see people working vert efficiently with GVIM, with lots of custom plugins. I know it is a steep learning curve but mat very well try it. Maybe a suggestion for a way to get GVIM smooth and functional under OSX? (Python, C++, bash, etc)

Thanks.